# How to place a file upload from an AJAX jQuery upload system into a mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying [to get this](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html) to instead of uploading files in a nice way and placing them on the server, to talk instead to some php that will (hopefully) place them into a MySQL database. I can get it posting just fine, but instead of returning anything useful - or succeeding - I get:

```
Error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

I do not know why. Firebug tells me it talks to the php just fine. I'm unsure how to extract the files which are posted under the name of "files[]" in php, to identify and handle them separately. I've not found any clear to understand method of extracting a posted array (I presume this is what it is?). Would this be causing the JSON.parse error, through not handling the end method well? Or is there something else going on before that?

New to AJAX, and now frustrated. Help appreciated.

[Originating form looks like this](http://pastebin.com/fx8h1kG2)

[Which pastes to this php](http://pastebin.com/PcaiXcpf) (currently does not a lot, yet)

[This is the main application script JS file](http://pastebin.com/LT9Z7dAt)

Comment: What does your JSON look like?

Comment: You should post any edits and code here so they are preserved for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Normally I would however I believe there is far too much code to fit on here. I've set the pastebin links not to expire though, for that very reason.

Comment: Ah, but if Pastebin ever goes away it doesn't matter what the settings are. You can likely whittle down your code to the most relevant parts too.

Comment: I don't think pastebin is too likely to go away, it's been pretty reliable for years. However if we get a resolution to this, I'd be tempted to spend the time whittling and consolidating it here for ease of use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you get jQueryFileUploader to do what you want is to subclass the class that does all the work on the server.

If you look at the file structure on the server where you installed the FileUploader it looks something like this

[image]

what gets run by default is the index.php in the `php` folder, and that instantiates the UploadHandler class like so

```
?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
   require('UploadHandler.php');
   $upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
```

And it is the code in that class that does all the actual work of putting files on disk etc etc...

Now to make it do what you want it to rather than its default process, you need to code your own functionality either instead of the default or as well as the default functionality.

So what you need to do is subclass the default class and override whichever method in the real class does the work you want to alter.

To change the process of uploading a file, you would add this method to your MyUploadHandler class

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');

class MyUploadHandler extends UploadHandler
{
    /*
     * Maintain our database:
     * For each uploaded file, add an entry to the tbl_xxx
     */
    protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, 
                                          $type, $error, $index = null, 
                                          $content_range = null)
    {
        // this does what woudl have automatically been done 
        // before we subclasses anything
        $file = parent::handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, 
                                           $type, $error, $index, 
                                           $content_range);

        /* Now we add some extra processing 
           if the file uploaded with no problems
         */
        if ( empty($file->error) ) {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_xxx ( a,b, imgpath)
                    VALUES('x', 'y', '$file->name' )";

            $db->query($sql);

        }
        return $file;
    }
} // end of class

$upload_handler = new MyUploadHandler($site_params);
```

Comment: That has helped hugely. I might even be able to figure out enough of what you've shown me to modify it to add all the variables contained in the hidden post data and enter it into my database table correctly. Big thanks for the very helpful and clear explanation, for a not-very-skilled php person like me. :)

Comment: Try here for some DOCS https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki and especially [How to submit additional form data](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data)

Comment: The docs are kinda useful but it would be sure nice if they hinted at how to actually put the files themselves into the database, not just the file information....

Comment: Look into the UploadHandler class and find the method that gets run to do the save to disk, then subclass that function to make it so what you want it to do.

Comment: Hi Riggs, yes that part I got from your earlier answer, it's just I'm not sure how to build it in php with files[] being one or multiple uploads at a time, to place it as a blob into the db, one entry per file.

Comment: I'm also trying to do everything in php with PDO.. which is also a new one on me. :/